# How to insert extra field with different parameter into stack

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, stack

I have three fields and I am inserting this into stack. I have another field which having different value and I want this filed to insert in stack. field is inserting but it inserting three times with all three field.

```
var array = [];
this.array.push({
value:value,
data: data
// All these parameter declered for three fields.
});
```

in my first field i Have Index which is not in next three field. so I n=inserted like

```
this.arry.push(Index,{
value:value,
data: data
// All these parameter declered for three fields.
});
```

But from this index is appearing before every fields. What is the corect way to do.  Thanks for help.

Comment: ya, thanks for notice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this it will allow to insert at position

```
array.splice(Index, 0, {value:value,data: data});
```

Comment: You mean during push operation.

Comment: But In this case Index is not adding in stack.

Comment: For that you need to insert like this [{index:index,value:value,data: data}]